# OBIEE 11 - How to export a multipage dashboard in excel without prompt

Tags: excel, export, prompt, obiee

I wonder if there is a way to export my multipage dashboard (realized in OBIEE 11) to excel avoiding prompt.
I've tried to set the prompt section collapsed by default. When I run the dashboard, the section is correctly collapsed, but if I export immediately the dashboard (without doing any action), I found the prompt in the excel!
I have noticed that when I open the section and then I collapse it again, and I repeat the export to excel, this time the prompts disappear!
I don't know why the first time it doesn't work and I have to uncollapse and collapse again the section to make it work.
Unfortunately this dashboard has to be downloaded on the file system and then sent by email.
So I can't do this trick with prompt.
Any help would be precious.
Thank you very much to anyone who could read and help.
Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things you can do:

1.) Use actual in-line prompts for dashboard pages. It's in the dashboard properties and then "Filters and Variables". There you can register prompts who won't be rendered visually but still execute as context filters for the page.

2.) You may want to look at Briefing Books as well: https://gerardnico.com/dat/obiee/briefing_book

Comment: Thank you very much Chris. About the way 1), the visibile prompts are used by user to set time to filter the data. Every day other users have to receive an email with and attach (excel file) whitout selection, with all data. The analysis are the same. I'm thinking about having two versions of the same dashboard, one with the prompt and one without. About the way 2) I'm going to study the distribution via agent of a brief book, but from a vary fast reading I can have just pdf/mhtml prints, and I strictly need to have an Excel format because users aggregate data on his own.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if you only want data dumps of the different objects, then a second page without prompts makes sense. This requirement wasn't very clear from the initial question.

Generally data dumps can be done in a more efficient way via the BI Server ODBC interface. Pushing things from the BI Server to the BI Presesntation Server to the Browser and then to the desktop is quite inefficient.